# one checked or multi checked in checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I'm using check box in form. but when one check box is checked, show the detail div. and when multi check not show the div with jquery.

HTML code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cb1" id="cb1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="cb2" id="cb2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="cb3" id="cb3" />
<input type="checkbox" name="cb4" id="cb4" />
<div id="detail" style="display:none"></div>
```

Comment: please add your code where you show #details div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the code :

Note : replace jquery library path

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Demo</title>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function checkIt(sender) {
        if ($(".checkme:checked").length == 1) {
            $("#detail").css({
                display:"block"
            });
        }
        else {
            $("#detail").css({
                display: "none"
            });
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="checkbox" name="cb1" id="cb1" class="checkme" onchange="checkIt(this);"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="cb2" id="cb2" class="checkme"  onchange="checkIt(this);" />
<input type="checkbox" name="cb3" id="cb3" class="checkme"  onchange="checkIt(this);" />
<input type="checkbox" name="cb4" id="cb4" class="checkme"  onchange="checkIt(this);"/>
<div id="detail" style="display: none">I am Here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you do it. Hope that helps.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cb1" id="cb1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="cb2" id="cb2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="cb3" id="cb3" />
<input type="checkbox" name="cb4" id="cb4" />
<div id="detail" style="display:none">Box.</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
    var count = 0;
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
        count = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;

        if (count == 1) {
            $('#detail').show();
        } else {
            $('#detail').hide();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood it right,i think you need to show the div when only 1 checkbox is checked and in other cases it should be hidden? If so,try this out..

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").on('click',function(){
    var c=0;
    $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){                
        if($(this).is(":checked"))
          c++;
     });

   (c==1) ? $("#detail").show() : $("#detail").hide();
});
```